# How to do foreach call

Tags: java, minecraft

I am iterating through all the players in a collection using a for call and Intellij said I could do a foreach call to do "easier".

Code snippet;

```
   private void closeInvs() {
    for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        p.closeInventory();
    }
}
```

Comment: @FarazDurrani I want to call foreach player in the collection and then close their inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().forEach( (p) -> p.closeInventory());
```

That should work.